# Git show diff in certain file

Tags: git

I'm using Github GUI and I've an old version of my project called 2.4, but the difference in a certain file is too big to be visible.

Can i through the commandline show the diff in the commit at: `8f135b0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
git show 8f135b0
```

... which show you the change introduced by that commit as a diff, as well as the commit message and other details.

Answer (score 1):

Between what and what? Current and the old commit?

`git diff HEAD 8f135b0`

More generally, `git-diff` can take two commits and show the diffs between them. HEAD is a symbolic name for the current head you are in.

See `man git-diff` for more info.

Comment: It says: $ git diff HEAD 8f135b0
fatal: ambiguous argument '8f135b0': unknown revision or path not in the working
 tree.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right commit #? Try a `git log` to double check.